# Definition of pencil of hypersurfaces.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

On Voisin's book Hodge theory and complex algebraic geometry II, she defined a pencil of hypersurfaces on a variety $X$ to be a projective line $\mathbb P^1 \subset P(H^0(X, L)) =: |L|$, where $L$ is a holomorphic line bundle on $X$.

But how is that different from the definition of a general pencil? Do we require the line bundle $L$ here from a diviosr $D$? (My definition of a pencil is: A pencil is a linear system of dimension $1$, i.e. a one-dimensional linear subspace of some $|D|$, where $|D|\subset Div(X)$ is the set of all effective divisors linearly equivalent to $D$ and $|D|\cong \mathcal{P}(L(D))\cong \mathcal{P}(H^0(X,\mathcal{O}([D]))$.)

Moreover, how is Voisin's definition related to the hypersurfaces? Does that implicitly imply the divisors in $\mathbb P^1\subset |L|$ to be hypersurfaces in $X$?

I wonder if Voisin's definition of the pencil of hypersurfaces is just the same as my definition of a pencil. But on Voisin's book, she has both divisor and hypersurface, I wonder if she abused the names here?

Comment: I have no idea, but maybe it is the distinction between Cartier and Weil divisors?

Comment: How are effective divisors $\textit{not}$ hypersurfaces?